# Bootstrap modal stops working after I sort portfolio

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, quicksand, bootbox

I am building a sortable portfolio using quicksand.js, to display more information on click I am using bootbox.js, now this is working pretty well but I recently ran into an issue. When you sort the portfolio bootbox not longer works!

[*You can see this in action here*](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/), scroll to the portfolio section and click one of the images to see it function correctly. Then sort it and try again and you will see my issue.

**Update:** *Using console I found what is causing the issue but I cant fully understand the error, I had to use jquery migrate at one point to make quicksand function and that is part of the issue. Here is the error:*

```
console.trace()                        jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43
migrateWarn                            jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43
Object.defineProperty.get              jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:58
$.fn.quicksand                         jquery.quicksand.js:34
(anonymous function)                   portfolio.js:36
jQuery.event.dispatch                  jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle                        jquery-1.9.1.js:2750
```

Here is my javascript:

```
    function gallery(){
        $('#branding1').click(function() { bootbox.alert('<h4>Beach Me</h4><hr><p class="subtitle"><em>Branding</em></p><img src="img/projects/branding1.jpg"><p class="project-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a elit turpis. Phasellus non varius mi. Nam bibendum in mauris at sollicitudin lacinia. Vestibulum blandit nibh neque, id consequat mi vestibulum eu.</p>'); });
        $('#web1').click(function() { bootbox.alert('<h4>Cloud INC.</h4><hr><p class="subtitle"><em>Branding</em></p><img src="img/projects/web1.jpg"><p class="project-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a elit turpis. Phasellus non varius mi. Nam bibendum in mauris at sollicitudin lacinia. Vestibulum blandit nibh neque, id consequat mi vestibulum eu.</p>'); });
        $('#print1').click(function() { bootbox.alert('<h4>steampuxk co.</h4><hr><p class="subtitle"><em>Branding</em></p><img src="img/projects/print1.jpg"><p class="project-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a elit turpis. Phasellus non varius mi. Nam bibendum in mauris at sollicitudin lacinia. Vestibulum blandit nibh neque, id consequat mi vestibulum eu.</p>'); });
        $('#branding2').click(function() { bootbox.alert('<h4>Life is Grand</h4><hr><p class="subtitle"><em>Branding</em></p><img src="img/projects/branding2.jpg"><p class="project-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a elit turpis. Phasellus non varius mi. Nam bibendum in mauris at sollicitudin lacinia. Vestibulum blandit nibh neque, id consequat mi vestibulum eu.</p>'); });
        $('#print2').click(function() { bootbox.alert('<h4>Snapshot</h4><hr><p class="subtitle"><em>Branding</em></p><img src="img/projects/print2.jpg"><p class="project-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a elit turpis. Phasellus non varius mi. Nam bibendum in mauris at sollicitudin lacinia. Vestibulum blandit nibh neque, id consequat mi vestibulum eu.</p>'); });
        $('#branding3').click(function() { bootbox.alert('<h4>Cityscape</h4><hr><p class="subtitle"><em>Branding</em></p><img src="img/projects/branding3.jpg"><p class="project-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a elit turpis. Phasellus non varius mi. Nam bibendum in mauris at sollicitudin lacinia. Vestibulum blandit nibh neque, id consequat mi vestibulum eu.</p>'); });
        $('#web2').click(function() { bootbox.alert('<h4>Details</h4><hr><p class="subtitle"><em>Branding</em></p><img src="img/projects/web2.jpg"><p class="project-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a elit turpis. Phasellus non varius mi. Nam bibendum in mauris at sollicitudin lacinia. Vestibulum blandit nibh neque, id consequat mi vestibulum eu.</p>'); });
        $('#print3').click(function() { bootbox.alert('<h4>SunnyDay</h4><hr><p class="subtitle"><em>Branding</em></p><img src="img/projects/print3.jpg"><p class="project-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a elit turpis. Phasellus non varius mi. Nam bibendum in mauris at sollicitudin lacinia. Vestibulum blandit nibh neque, id consequat mi vestibulum eu.</p>'); });
        $('#web3').click(function() { bootbox.alert('<h4>Train Station</h4><hr><p class="subtitle"><em>Branding</em></p><img src="img/projects/web3.jpg"><p class="project-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a elit turpis. Phasellus non varius mi. Nam bibendum in mauris at sollicitudin lacinia. Vestibulum blandit nibh neque, id consequat mi vestibulum eu.</p>'); });
    }
var $itemsHolder = $('ul.thumbnails');
var $itemsClone = $itemsHolder.clone(); 
var $filterClass = "";
$('ul.filter li').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$filterClass = $(this).attr('data-value');
    if($filterClass == 'all'){ var $filters = $itemsClone.find('li'); }
    else { var $filters = $itemsClone.find('li[data-type='+ $filterClass +']'); }
    $itemsHolder.quicksand(
      $filters,
      { duration: 1000 },
      gallery
      );
});
$(document).ready(gallery);
```

and my html:

```
<!-- Begin Portfolio -->
<section id="section2">

    <div class="container portfolio">

        <!-- Page Title -->
        <div class="row page-title">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3>Portfolio</h3>
                <hr>
                <p>We also create some other stuff.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Portfolio Filter -->
        <div class="container text-center">
          <ul id="filterOptions" class="filter nav nav-pills center-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="all">all</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="print">print</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="web">web</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="branding">branding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="apps">apps</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="graphic design">graphic design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="illustation">illustration</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Portfolio Items -->
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="ourHolder no-padding">
            <li class="item col-lg-4 no-padding" data-id="id-1" data-type="branding">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="branding1">
                    <img src="img/projects/thumbs/branding1.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <span class="portfolio-hover">
                      <span>
                        <h4>Beach Me</h4>
                        <em>Branding</em>
                      </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-lg-4 no-padding" data-id="id-2" data-type="web">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="web1">
                    <img src="img/projects/thumbs/web1.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <span class="portfolio-hover">
                      <span>
                        <h4>Chris Harbour</h4>
                        <em>Web Design</em>
                      </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-lg-4 no-padding" data-id="id-3" data-type="print">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="print1">
                    <img src="img/projects/thumbs/print1.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <span class="portfolio-hover">
                      <span>
                        <h4>Bildende</h4>
                        <em>Print</em>
                      </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-lg-4 no-padding" data-id="id-4" data-type="branding">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="branding2">
                    <img src="img/projects/thumbs/branding2.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <span class="portfolio-hover">
                      <span>
                        <h4>SK Invitational</h4>
                        <em>Branding</em>
                      </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-lg-4 no-padding" data-id="id-5" data-type="print">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="print2">
                    <img src="img/projects/thumbs/print2.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <span class="portfolio-hover">
                      <span>
                        <h4>Magz Killa</h4>
                        <em>Print</em>
                      </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-lg-4 no-padding" data-id="id-6" data-type="branding">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="branding3">
                    <img src="img/projects/thumbs/branding3.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <span class="portfolio-hover">
                      <span>
                        <h4>Synex</h4>
                        <em>Branding</em>
                      </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-lg-4 no-padding" data-id="id-7" data-type="web">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="web2">
                    <img src="img/projects/thumbs/web2.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <span class="portfolio-hover">
                      <span>
                        <h4>Cow</h4>
                        <em>Web Design</em>
                      </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-lg-4 no-padding" data-id="id-8" data-type="print">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="print3">
                    <img src="img/projects/thumbs/print3.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <span class="portfolio-hover">
                      <span>
                        <h4>Tehc9btcxh</h4>
                        <em>Print</em>
                      </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item col-lg-4 no-padding" data-id="id-9" data-type="web">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="web3">
                    <img src="img/projects/thumbs/web3.jpg" alt="..." />
                    <span class="portfolio-hover">
                      <span>
                        <h4>Infobook</h4>
                        <em>Branding</em>
                      </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</section>
<!-- End Portfolio -->
```

I havent had any luck with this if anyone could take look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: I saw that the quicksand plugin allows for a callback function.

I believe what's happening here is the elements are losing their event handlers when they get sorted due to the elements being cloned and the `gallery()` function only being called on `(document).ready`. The elements that display after being sorted are 'new' and have not got an event listener attached.

In portfolio.js, try calling the `gallery()` function after sorting the items via the quicksand callback argument

```
...

// call quicksand and assign transition parameters
$holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
  duration: 800,
  easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
}, gallery);

...
```

Also, I see that you have gallery as the callback in the code you posted here, but I don't think that's the code that is running. I think portfolio.js is what's running to do the sorting.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense now, worked perfectly! Im totally new to javascript so this answer helped a lot, thank you.